# Creating Relational Database in Pandas and SQL?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlite

I would like to use SQL with Pandas and I was able to successfully create a SQL database from a dataframe in Pandas and use SQL commands to query the data (see below code). I would now like to create a relational database, based on unique keys within the three csv files (the key exists in all three files). How do I go about doing this?

## Create sql database

```
import pandas as pd

from sqlalchemy import create_engine # database connection

import datetime as dt

from IPython.display import display

disk_engine = create_engine('sqlite:///ffm3.db') 



start = dt.datetime.now()
chunksize = 20000
j = 0
index_start = 1

for df in pd.read_csv('...Geofence.csv', iterator=True, encoding='utf-8'):

df = df.rename(columns={c: c.replace(' ', '') for c in df.columns}) # Remove spaces from columns

df['EnteredDT'] = pd.to_datetime(df['EnteredDT']) # Convert to datetimes
df['ExitedDT'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ExitedDT'])

df["Name"] = df["Name"].astype(str)
df["Name"] = df["Name"].map(str.strip)




df.index += index_start


j+=1
print '{} seconds: completed {} rows'.format((dt.datetime.now() - start).seconds, j*chunksize)

df.to_sql('data', disk_engine, if_exists='append')
index_start = df.index[-1] + 1
```

Comment: *I would now like to create a relational database*...why? SQLite is a powerful RDMS available at file level. So use it to import all csv files, set indexes, and run joins as needed. Use pandas as the end use app to import a query resultset only for analytical purposes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So you are saying run joints using SQLite while in Pandas, correct? If so, is there documentation on this? And what do you mean by set indexes?

Comment: More specifically: I am doing worker analysis and I have three datasets from smart phones in csv format, one on worker location, one on battery life and another on whether they are going to a specific location. The datasets are very different so I don't see a way to merge them in Pandas. They do have a common key and that is the worker ID number. I would like to query a name (or name and time period) and return fields important for the analysis.

Comment: Again, simply import all three pieces into SQLite. From command line, you can use the [csv mode](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html) to import data to tables. Pandas can call SQL queries with [read_sql](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html). And the [SQLite API](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) comes built-in with Python installations.